# (WP) Override Plugin Function In Theme Functions

Tags: wordpress

How to override function inside plugin and put in theme functions.php file? I've try using remove_filter and add_filter, apply_filter, add_action etc, but still not worked.

https://github.com/mikejolley/WP-Job-Manager/blob/master/wp-job-manager-template.php#L72

I want to override function on line 72. How can I done this? I don't want to edit plugin files because I just want this function replaced only when this theme activated. If not activated, function will be as the original function.

Answer (score 1):

This function used by plugin. And no any filters or actions inside. So, my sorry, you can't solve this issue.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to override public function in plugin class to theme functions.php file?